# Is there a way to change code formating for curly braces in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

By default Format is

```
void df(){
//some
}
```

But I prefer like this:

```
void df()
{
//some
}
```

Anyway to do it? Can't seem to find in preferences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot check in Android Studio but in Intellij

Editor -> Code Style -> Java -> Wrapping and Braces -> Braces placement -> select the option you want

Answer (score 3):

> Settings > Editor > Code Style > Java > Wrapping and Braces

Image taken from the internet as I do not have access to Android Studio at the moment, but you can see the tab at the top
[image: here]